# SqlParameter constructor compiler overload choice

Tags: c#, ado.net, overloading

When creating an `SqlParameter` (.NET3.5) or `OdbcParameter`, I often use the `SqlParameter(string parameterName, Object value)` constructor overload to set the value in one statement.

However, when I tried passing a literal 0 as the value parameter, I was initially caught by the C# compiler choosing the `(string, OdbcType)` overload instead of `(string, Object)`.

MSDN actually warns about this gotcha in the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but the explanation confuses me.

Why does the C# compiler decide that a literal 0 parameter should be converted to `OdbcType` rather than `Object`?  The warning also says to use `Convert.ToInt32(0)` to force the `Object` overload to be used.

It confusingly says that this converts the 0 to an "Object type". But isn't 0 already an "Object type"? The [Types of Literal Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) section of this page seems to say literals are always typed and so inherit from `System.Object`.

This behavior doesn't seem very intuitive.  Is this something to do with Contra-variance or Co-variance maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [C# Language Specification 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e&displaylang=en):

> the literal 0 implicitly converts to
>   any enum type.

So `SqlParameter("parameterName", 0)` resolves to the `SqlParameter(string, OdbcType)` overload.

If you change to `SqlParameter("parameterName", 1)` it resolves to the `SqlParameter(string, object)` overload.  The same logic applies to `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 1):

0 is the default value of any enum. Hence it is the more exact match than object.

Comment: So the values of parameters are used by the compiler to match overloads if Type checking is not enough?  I thought the type of a parameter, or its base types, were the only information used.  I knew that the default type of an enum is an integer, but was not aware of this.